# Display the same listview element in VB.NET in 2 different forms

Tags: vb.net, listview

i've 2 Forms in a VB.Net app
in Form1 i've a Listview element
i want to display the same Listview in Form2 but with a different size
what is the best way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: What part of this task are you having trouble with?  Is this a WinForm application?  Where is the data coming from?

Comment: yes its winform app in VB.NET ,data coming from google shopping API Atom format,i parsed the atom feed and filled the data in Listview1, i am not a real programmer and i wonder if there is a built in functionality to show the same Listview in Form1 in Form2 when i show it, just like copy paste the Listview1 to Form2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no built-in method for copying the contents of one `ListView` control to another. Rather, you should be restructuring your code so that the business logic is separated from the UI. Both the logic to get the data from the API and the logic to populate a `ListView` control with that data ought to be in a separate common class that can be used by any form.  In order to do that, you will need to store the data in memory in some kind of data structure that is easily passed between forms, classes, and methods. For instance, if each item in the list can be represented as an `Atom` class, I would recommend using a `List(Of Atom)` object to hold the data. For instance, your common class could be something along these lines:

```
Public Class ShoppingBusiness
    Public Function GetData() As List(Of Atom)
        ' Get data from API and return it as a List(Of Atom) object
    End Function        

    Public Sub LoadList(atoms As List(Of Atom), list As ListView)
        ' Load the ListView control with the data
    End Sub
End Class
```

Once the business logic is broken out into it's own class like that, you can then easily access all of the logic from any form without duplicating all that code.  However, rather than having both forms, in this example, call `ShoppingBusiness.GetData`, because that's probably a slow method, you will want to do it just once, and then use the same data to populate both `ListView` controls.  For instance, if `Form1` shows `Form2`, it could do it like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _data As List(Of Atom)
    Private _business As ShoppingBusiness = New ShoppingBusiness()

    Private Sub refreshList()
        _data = _business.GetData()
        _business.LoadList(_data, ListView1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub showForm2()
        Dim form2 As Form2 = New Form2()
        form2.Data = _data
        form2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Private _data As List(Of Atom)
    Private _business As ShoppingBusiness = New ShoppingBusiness()

    Public Property Data() As List(Of Atom)
        Get
            Return _data
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Atom))
            _data = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub refreshList()
        _business.LoadList(_data, ListView2)
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see in this example, Form1 will keep a copy of the data in memory after it gets it.  It keeps the data in it's private `_data` field.  When it creates a new `Form2` object, before it shows it, it gives it a reference to the data that it already has in memory.  Then, `Form2` can use the same `LoadList` method to load the data into the list, but it doesn't have to get the data from the API again because the data was given to it by `Form1`.