# How display data in 2 listview in different forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

I have a form (form1) with one listview and other controls.This ListView is filled with data. I wont to have same data in other form (form2) in ListView. 
In this case I created a method RefreshForm with paramater listView.

```
Public Sub RefreshForm(ByVal listView As ListView)
   On Error Resume Next
   ListView2 = listView
   ListView2.Refresh()
   On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

In form1 in constructor I initialize form2 and show it.

```
form2 = new Form_CustInfo()
fCustInfo.Show()
```

After in method where I fill listView from form1 at end of method where listview is filled with data I call method RefreshForm from form2

```
form2.RefreshForm(Me.ListView2)
```

In method I entred with debug and I sow listview filled with data (ListView2 have 5 items) but and after refresh listview from form2 does't display this items.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the Data Items instead of the control?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display the same listview element in VB.NET in 2 different forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285252/display-the-same-listview-element-in-vb-net-in-2-different-forms)